# Makefile not processing all commands

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I am trying to convert a hello.c to hello stepwise by first preprocessing then compiling, then assembling then linking. However only the first command of my makefile is being executed:

```
Osheens-MacBook-Air-1115:Assignment0.1 osheensachdev$ ls
hello.c     makefile
Osheens-MacBook-Air-1115:Assignment0.1 osheensachdev$ cat makefile

hello.i : hello.c
    gcc -E hello.c -o hello.i

hello.s : hello.i
    gcc -S hello.i -o hello.s

hello.o : hello.s
    gcc -c hello.s -o hello.o

hello : hello.o
    $ld hello.o -e main hello

clean:
    rm hello.i hello.s hello.o hello
Osheens-MacBook-Air-1115:Assignment0.1 osheensachdev$ make
gcc -E hello.c -o hello.i
Osheens-MacBook-Air-1115:Assignment0.1 osheensachdev$ make
make: `hello.i' is up to date.
```

I've searched online about chained files and didn't find anything specific about why this shouldn't work.

I've also specified the `target: [dependancies]` so I don't see why this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first target of a Makefile is the default target.

This is why you see in many Makefiles a `all` target at the top which is intended to "make everything":

```
all: build test

build: <prerequisites>

test: <prerequisites>
```

Since you didn't specify one, Make builds `hello.i` only (plus everything needed to build this target):

1. `hello.i` doesn't exist yet.
2. `hello.i` needs `hello.c`. Make `hello.c` first.
3. `hello.c` is "made" already. Nothing to do.
4. Now make `hello.i` i.e., run `gcc -E hello.c -o hello.i`.
5. Stop

Then you ran Make again (without any specific target)

1. `hello.i` exists already. Nothing to do.
2. Stop.

I suspect that you wanted to make "hello", i.e., your program.

Either:

1. Move "hello" at the top and make it your default target
2. Or run `make hello`